# Stata vs. R: Delta Method provides different results for relative risk SE's from logit model

Tags: r, stata

I've been trying to estimate the conditional mean treatment effect of covariates in a logit regression (using relative-risk) along with their standard errors for inference purposes. The delta method is necessary to calculated the standard errors for these treatment effects. I've been trying to recreate these results using the Stata user written command, `adjrr`, to calculate the relative risk with standard errors and confidence intervals in R.

The `adjrr` command in Stata calculates the adjusted relative-risk (the conditional mean treatment effect of interest for my project) and it's SE's using the delta method. The `deltamethod` command in R should create the same results, however this is not the case.

How can I replicate the results from Stata in R?

I used the following self generated data: (https://migariane.github.io/DeltaMethodEpiTutorial.nb.html).

R code below:

```
generateData <- function(n, seed){
    set.seed(seed)
    age <- rnorm(n, 65, 5)
    age65p <- ifelse(age>=65, T, F)
    cmbd <- rbinom(n, size=1, prob = plogis(1 - 0.05 * age))
    Y <- rbinom(n, size=1, prob = plogis(1 - 0.02* age - 0.02 * cmbd))
    data.frame(Y, cmbd, age, age65p)
}

# Describing the data
data <- generateData(n = 1000, seed = 777) 
str(data)

logfit <- glm(Y ~ age65p + cmbd, data = data, family = binomial)
summary(logfit)

p1 <- predict(logfit, newdata = data.frame(age65p = T, cmbd = 0), type="response")
p0 <- predict(logfit, newdata = data.frame(age65p = F, cmbd = 0), type="response")
rr <- p1 / p0
rr
0.8123348 #result

library(msm)
se_rr_delta <- deltamethod( ~(1 + exp(-x1)) / (1 + exp(-x1 -x2)), coef(logfit), vcov(logfit))
se_rr_delta
0.6314798 #result
```

Stata Code (using same data):

```
logit Y i.age65p i.cmbd

adjrr age65p

//results below
R1  = 0.3685 (0.0218)    95% CI  (0.3259, 0.4112)
R0  = 0.4524 (0.0222)    95% CI  (0.4090, 0.4958)
ARR = 0.8146 (0.0626)    95% CI  (0.7006, 0.9471)
ARD = -0.0839 (0.0311)    95% CI  (-0.1449, -0.0229)
p-value (R0 = R1):  0.0071
p-value (ln(R1/R0) = 0):  0.0077
```

Comment: You likely checked this, but I was curious if your variables are the same type in both softwares. I've seen some stuff about variation in models because of the way each handles variable types.

Comment: Great question. They are same, and the same coefficients and SE's are produced by the glm (R) and logit (Stata) regression commands.

Comment: If you check the `coefficient` and `se` values from Stata and R, they are the same. If any inconsistent there, you may want to check `adjrr` instead.

Comment: Confirmed. The coefficients, SE's, and the covariance matrix are the same in both Stata and R.